# How did the video of sergeant Brody end up in Saul's hands?

Tags: plot-explanation, homeland

So, before sergeant Brody was to blow up the room filled with American politicians in *Homeland*, he made a video in which he "explains himself". In season 2 Carrie retrieves a bag with some documents she grabbed from the apartment of a man (Abbas Ali) after he was shot by Americans during his meeting with Abu Nazir in Beirut. At the end of episode 2 Saul finds the mentioned video of sergeant Brody sewn into the side of the bag...

I missed the process of this memory card ending up in the bag of the guy that was mentioned for the first time in the series. But it is possible that this Abbas Ali appeared before, and I just forgot. Can anyone fill me up on this?

Comment: He left the flash drive in the park by the bench. When he returned it was missing, with a marking to indicate that it had been retrieved by the other party. I believe that the terrorist network would have been told to pick this up prior to the bombing, and then it made its way (unseen on screen I think) to the owner of the bag in series 2. I don't think it was addressed on screen at all.

Comment: Yeah... I also guessed it happen like that, but it just seems weird for them to leave this unexplained since this video made a turning point in the series... that's why I assumed I've missed something.

Comment: Pure speculation, but I suspect it was left intentionally vague so that the audience could draw their own conclusions. Though there may be an official answer out there, I've not checked that hard just yet :)

Comment: @Longshanks I believe that what you wrote in the comments above is conclusive enough. I will accept it as correct, if you write it in the answer section. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Most likely picked up by a member of the terrorist network, who had been instructed to deliver it to Abbas Ali.

What we know about the memory card:

- It was left by Brody in a specific location
- When Brody returned, the video was gone, and a simple mark left on the wall
- The card then ended up in Abbas Ali's possession

It seems likely that the network were watching the drop-off point, waiting for Brody, and as soon as the card was there they picked it up and delivered it.